# CodeIgniter MySQL LIKE query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I am trying to get result from advertisement table by searching phone number from using **mysql** "LIKE" query. I tried many times but I did not get result.

```
public function searching($key){
     
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('advertisement');
    $this->db->where('phone',$key);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        echo "YES";
    }
    else{
        echo "NO";
    }
}
```

I got "YES" as a result when using "where" clause. But when I searching same phone number with "like" clause(`$this->db->like('phone',$key);`) instead of "where", I got "NO", as a result.

Comment: I would try and run the query straight in MySQL. I doubt this will be a problem with codeigniter but rather some setting or config on the database. Try and run it direct and see if that provides any help.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I should change? I am doing my first codeigniter project. So I do know much about it

Comment: Try to get your query working correctly as pure MySQL and then once it is, you can work from there.

Comment: Let me see the log. Use `log_message('debug', $this->db->last_query());`  af the end of the function.

Comment: $query = SELECT * FROM advertisement;

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected 'advertisement' (T_STRING)       , I got this error when I ran above mentioned simple code.

Comment: What is you php version, check `php --version`  . If it is too old update.

Comment: version is 3.1.11.

Comment: Please upgrade, many of the functions will not work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that was codignitor version. php version is 7.3.33

Comment: `$this->db->where('phone like "%'.$key.'%"'); ` try this, see what is the output.

Comment: use wlidcard with like 
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both');

Comment: Thanks for both of your support. I tried both codes. Both did not worked. Code is not working properly if "LIKE" in that code. Do I have to change config file when using mysql "LIke"?

Comment: My first thought is that *phone* is a INTEGER, you cannot use LIKE on an Integer field.  Hence it is failing.  And in regards to Steve's $query comment, you forgot to Quote it and you would get a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks forbs. I didn't know that.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks all for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding it as an answer for future seekers.

The field PHONE is probably setup as an INTEGER and you cannot use LIKE on an integer.  There will be a mysql error thrown but if debug is off or something else is turned off it will never show.