# CodeIgniter Where query is working BUT LIKE query is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, config, autoload

I am trying to get result from advertisement table by searching phone number from using mysql "LIKE" query. I tried many times but I did not get result.

```
public function searching($key){
     
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('advertisement');
    $this->db->where('phone',$key);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        echo "YES";
    }
    else{
        echo "NO";
    }
}
```

I got "YES" as a result when using "where" clause.

But when searching the same phone number with "like" instead of "where" clause:

```
$this->db->like('phone',$key);
```

I get "NO", as a result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter MySQL LIKE query is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108372/codeigniter-mysql-like-query-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Steve, You can use "$this->db->like()" to make LIKE query.

Replace your "where" with "like".

```
$this->db->like('phone', $key);
```

More information can be found [CI3 documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data).

Comment: yes. I did that. When I used that code I got result as "NO".

Comment: Try with $this->db->like('phone', $key, 'before');

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried that code. Both did not worked. Code is not working properly if "LIKE" in that code. Do I have to change config file when using mysql "LIke"?